# Setting DataContext in TabControl

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, tabcontrol, datacontext

I have a TabControl that is bound to an observable collection of Employees like so

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}">
            <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <views:EmployeeView/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        </TabControl>
```

I have set my DataTemplate to my employee view.  Say I have two employees in my Employees collection.  I get the proper tabs to appear.  In my EmployeeView I have a checkbox.  If I do not bind this checkbox it gets checked on all tabs.  I'm not sure I am following why this is happening.  I guess my question is how would I set the DataContext on the EmployeeView so that that the tabcontrols tabs would operate independently.

Comment: Is your CheckBox set to 'IsChecked = true' in XAML?

Comment: No sir, everything works as expected if i bind to a vm...  However, the checkbox i have just uses the code behind to expand or collapse a section of the view.  I do not have it bound to anything.  When i check it on one of my employees it expands on all of them.  Not the behavior i am wanting.  Hopefully this makes a bit more sense, thanks.

Comment: I have suggested an answer though I am not sure why all your customer views are expanded when one is expanded. From my experience the unbound controls in a bound `TabControl` simply lose their state when switching between tabs. For example a previously expanded `Expander` would be collapsed if I moved from tab A to B then back to A, rather than the `Expander` being expanded in all tabs.

Comment: can you upload more code? thanks

Comment: Did you have any luck after disabling the `TabControl`'s virtualisation?

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be that when the `TabControl` is databound it 'virtualises' its TabItems, unloading then reloading and rebinding their content when selection changes.

So you could try either binding the `IsChecked` of the CheckBox in your `View` to a property of its `ViewModel`, or disable the `TabItem` virtualisation with a behaviour such as the one here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/460989/WPF-TabControl-Turning-Off-Tab-Virtualization

I used the above behaviour recently myself as I had a similar issue with TabControl's default databound behaviour.